# Grouping by ID and getting multinomial distribution column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame like so:

```
    id  test
0   1   1.000000
1   2   0.582594
2   2   0.417406
3   3   0.016633
4   3   0.983367
5   4   1.000000
6   5   0.501855
7   5   0.498145
8   6   1.000000
9   7   1.000000
```

I want to use the `np.random.multinomial()` function to generate a new column (`target`) where for each ID i will generate either 1 or 0 depending on the test column (which are probabilities for the argument `pvals`). But for each id, the sum of the new column `target` will always be 1.

For example for id 2, i would get maybe something like the array in the commented code

```
np.random.multinomial(n = 1, pvals = [0.582594, 0.417406])
# array([1, 0])
```

I would then want to create the new column like so where I may having values like this, but obviously the multinomial distribution is probabilistic.

```
    id  test       target
0   1   1.000000   1
1   2   0.582594   1
2   2   0.417406   0
3   3   0.016633   0
4   3   0.983367   1
5   4   1.000000   1 
6   5   0.501855   0
7   5   0.498145   1
8   6   1.000000   1
9   7   1.000000   1
```

How can I do this in python without writing a loop to iterate through each id and doing this iteratively?

Comment: Do you always have 1 or 2 values per id?

Comment: It can be anywhere from 1 -5 values per id

Comment: can you update your example with one id with more than 2 values?

Answer (score 1):

```
output=df.groupby('id')['test'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.random.multinomial(n=1, pvals=x))).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).astype(int)


pd.merge(df, output, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Try steps

- group the data frame by ID using `groupby()`
- Apply the function to each group using `apply()`
- Use `reset_index()` to convert back to dataframe
- Finally merge the frames

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7],
    'test': [1.000000, 0.582594, 0.417406, 0.016633, 0.983367, 1.000000, 0.501855, 0.498145, 1.000000, 1.000000]
})

def generate_target_column(group):
    target_array = np.random.multinomial(n=1, pvals=group['test'], size=1)[0]
    target_series = pd.Series(target_array, index=group.index)
    return target_series

df['target'] = df.groupby('id').apply(generate_target_column).values

print(df)
```

which gives

```
  id      test  target
0   1  1.000000       1
1   2  0.582594       0
2   2  0.417406       1
3   3  0.016633       0
4   3  0.983367       1
5   4  1.000000       1
6   5  0.501855       1
7   5  0.498145       0
8   6  1.000000       1
9   7  1.000000       1
```

**EDIT**

For just a bit faster, you can use `transform` by doing thi:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7],
    'test': [1.000000, 0.582594, 0.417406, 0.016633, 0.983367, 1.000000, 0.501855, 0.498145, 1.000000, 1.000000]
})

def generate_target_column(group):
    target_array = np.random.multinomial(n=1, pvals=group['test'], size=1)[0]
    target_series = pd.Series(target_array, index=group.index)
    return target_series
st = time.time()

df['target'] = df.groupby('id')['test'].transform(lambda x: np.random.multinomial(n=1, pvals=x, size=1)[0])
et = time.time()
elapsed_time = et - st
print('Execution time:', elapsed_time, 'seconds')
```

which gives

```
Execution time: 0.0030193328857421875 seconds
```

while the previous solution had an execution time

```
Execution time: 0.004997968673706055 seconds
```

Comment: apply can he quite slow if the dataset is larger.. is there a more efficient alternative to appllyy?

Comment: @Eisen I updated my answer. If this isn't fast enough, try ```cython```. I did try ```dask```but it was actully slowe.r